# How can i setup multiple access points with multiple wifi cards on linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, hostapd

I've got an old PC with debian on it, which works as some kind of router. It is set up as wireless access point using hostapd.
I want to setup multiple access points, one on old wifi card with 2.4hz, and one on new one with 5hz. I wonder if there is a way to do that?

Comment: I haven't tried something but googling yet. I'm not very good with linux, but i thought it could be possible by running multiple instances of hostapd or by some setup of hostapd itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

The major difficulty lies in persuading hostapd to use 5GHz channels. This is mostly an issue with regulatory domain: you must set a country where such communication is legal. But I found it impossible to change the "world" domain built into the in-kernel version of my driver. In my case, I ended up recompiling the ath9k driver, with a modification intended to make it disregard completely the EEPROM code.

I ended up writing a concise yet complete summary of the steps involved [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2032357)

Comment: Thank you for provided tutorial. But my question is mostly about how can i run multiple access points on single system. Can you give me some clue about this issue?

Comment: Same thing as you already did. Don't you have a bridge between ethernet and wireless? Configure a new instance of hostapd, running on a different configuration file, but still joining the same bridge.